# How to search, replace and append a pattern to the end of each line

Tags: sed, replace, patterns

I have the following list of items:

```
bigBone
fishMarket
dogCollar
...
```

I need to generate a two character mapping like this:

```
bigBone -> bb
fishMarket -> fm
dogCollar -> dc
...
```

How can I create the above mapping using `sed`?

I have tried something like:

```
sed -i -r 's/^([a-z]{1})[a-z]+([A-Z]{1})[a-zA-Z]+/ -> \1\L\2/' file
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9591744), but not sure how to incorporate the concept here. Thanks.

Comment: See the comment of Stephane Chazelas to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you want to keep the whole line and just append something:

```
sed -r 's/^([a-z]{1})([a-z]+)([A-Z]{1})([a-zA-Z]+)$/\1\2\3\4 -> \1\L\3/' file
```

**edit**:

devnull had to remind me of it that there is an easy solution to this:

```
sed -r 's/^([a-z]{1})[a-z]+([A-Z]{1})[a-zA-Z]+/& -> \1\L\2/' file
```

Or, a bit more elegant (than my first try):

```
sed -r '
h
s/^([a-z]{1})[a-z]+([A-Z]{1})[a-zA-Z]+/ -> \1\L\2/
t append
b
: append
H
g
s/\n//' file
```

Comment: @QuestionOverflow It is even simpler, see the edit.

Comment: ranges like `[a-z]` only make sense in the POSIX or C locales. So you'd want either `LC_ALL=C sed ...` or to use `[[:lower:]]` instead. Note that `{1}` is redundant.

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/(.)[^[:upper:]]*(.).*/& -> \1\L\2/' inputfile
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
bigBone -> bb
fishMarket -> fm
dogCollar -> dc
```

Answer (score 3):

To generalise to `fooBarBaz -> fbb`, `abCdEfGh -> aceg`, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(.)(.*)/\1\n\2 -> \L\1/;:1
        s/\n([^[:upper:]]*([[:upper:]]))(.*)/\1\n\3\L\2/;t1;s/\n//'
```

POSIX `sed` doesn't have `\L`. So portably, you'd have to resort to using `y` and manually enter all the characters you want converted to lowercase. Something like:

```
LC_ALL=C sed '/^\([[:alpha:]]\).*/{
h;s//\1/;y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/;G
s/\(.\).\(.\)\(.*\)/\2\
\3 -> \1/;:1
/.*\n[^A-Z]*\([A-Z]\).*/{h;s//\1/
y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/;G
s/^\(.\)\n\(.*\)\n\([^A-Z]*[A-Z]\)\(.*\)/\2\3\
\4\1/;t1
}
s/\n//;}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is with a POSIX compliant script. I wasn't aware that POSIX `sed` leaves the behavior of `s///[n]g` unspecified, but, [sure enough](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html), it is not a well-defined behavior. Anyway, it's easy to handle without it - I just don't like using too many back-references if it can be helped, usually.

```
sed '/^[a-z]*[A-Z].*$/{ h
    s/\(.\)[^A-Z]*/\1/g
    y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/
    H ; g 
    s/\n/ -> /
    }' <<\DATA
bigBone
fishMarket
dogCollar
DATA

#OUTPUT
bigBone -> bb
fishMarket -> fm
dogCollar -> dc
```

Comment: Have you tried that? Doesn't work here (upper case vs. lower case)).

Comment: @HaukeLaging - I just needed to fix `y/` - it would have worked as it was if I had used `-r` but there's no need whatsoever to write a non-portable script for such a simple application. If it was you who downvoted this post and you did so due to the case conversion, that issue is resolved, and it is now faster and more portable than your own script. I believe you should reverse that vote.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - even better now. Thank you, Hauke. I expect that was you.

Comment: Speed? A rare argument with sed. More interesting may be what happens if your and my version hit a line which does not match this pattern ("foo bar")... Sure, that may be impossible depending on the input.

Comment: @HaukeLauking - `sed` is made for speed! In any case, your point on mispatched patterns is very good - and it is another way to improve speed. Just a moment...

Comment: `\L` is GNU specific anyway, so you might as well use `-r`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - it is? So the only way to do it portably is with `y/ABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz/` ?

Comment: @mikeserv, yes.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - so be it. At least its clear this way. And I got the addressing pretty specific, Hauke.

Comment: [`s///2g` is not portable/POSIX either](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) you also need to fix the locale to C or POSIX

Comment: `\|` is not portable/POSIX either.

Comment: Seriously, @StephaneChezales? `OR\|` isnt portable? I got both of those from the Grymoire. And its pretty old, too. I think hes even got a letter or two from you in that manual of his in there somewhere... I thought it was portable code. I can easily do it without it. Im just... Kinda done with it... Oh well, ill fix it. By the way - have you got the `sed` specs memorized or something? I couldnt remember all of those ins and outs like that. Youre definitely one of a kind.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just similar to @devnull's,

```
$ sed 's/\(.\).*\([A-Z]\).*/& -> \1\L\2/g' file
bigBone -> bb
fishMarket -> fm
dogCollar -> dc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `perl`, try:

```
$ perl -MList::Util=first -F// -aple '$_ .= " -> ".$F[0].lc(first{ord() < 97} @F)' file
bigBone -> bb
fishMarket -> fm
dogCollar -> dc
```